# Is type equality preserved across application in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

In haskell, does `s k v ~ s1 k1 v1`, where `s :: * -> * -> *`, imply that `k ~ k1`, `v ~ v1`, or `s ~ s1`? If not, why doesn't it?

I encountered this when writing some experimental code, a small piece of which is:

```
newtype Article = Article String
newtype ArticleId = ArticleId Int
newtype Comment = Comment String
newtype CommentId = CommentId Int

data TableName k v where
    Articles :: TableName ArticleId Article
    Comments :: TableName CommentId Comment    

data CRUD k v r where
    Create :: v -> CRUD k v k
    Read :: k -> CRUD k v (Maybe v)

data Operation t r where
    Operation :: s k v -> CRUD k v r -> Operation (s k v) r        

operatesOn :: (Eq (s k v)) => s k v -> Operation (s k v) r -> Bool
operatesOn tableName1 (Operation tableName2 _) = tableName1 == tableName2
```

Which doesn't compile due to the following error:

```
Could not deduce (v1 ~ v)
from the context (Eq (s k v))
  bound by the type signature for
             operatesOn :: Eq (s k v) => s k v -> Operation (s k v) r -> Bool
or from (s k v ~ s1 k1 v1)
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             Operation :: forall r (s :: * -> * -> *) k v.
                          s k v -> CRUD k v r -> Operation (s k v) r,
           in an equation for `operatesOn'
  `v1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       a pattern with constructor
         Operation :: forall r (s :: * -> * -> *) k v.
                      s k v -> CRUD k v r -> Operation (s k v) r,
       in an equation for `operatesOn'
       at src\Example\Error.hs:44:24
  `v' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        operatesOn :: Eq (s k v) => s k v -> Operation (s k v) r -> Bool
      at src\Example\Error.hs:43:15
Expected type: s k v
  Actual type: s1 k1 v1
In the second argument of `(==)', namely `tableName2'
In the expression: tableName1 == tableName2
In an equation for `operatesOn':
    operatesOn tableName1 (Operation tableName2 _)
      = tableName1 == tableName2
```

Comment: The whole example is done, it was to answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18378077/414413.

Comment: [Type application is injective](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990891/does-type-equality-imply-kind-equality), but that wasn't the problem. The deleted answer held helpful insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change the definition of Operation to

```
data Operation t r where
    Operation :: (t ~ s k v) => t -> CRUD k v r -> Operation t r
```

The operatesOn function will compile, similar to how it did for Maybe

The `(t ~ s k v) =>` constraint(?) will still reject incorrect programs like:

`doesntCompile = Operation Article $ Create $ Comment "Yo"`

Comment: There was another answer, which answered the question that I asked directly, on which I discussed what happens with the `Maybe` data type. `sameAsMaybe :: (Eq (s k v)) => s k v -> Maybe (s k v) -> Bool` defined as `sameAsMaybe a (Just b) = a == b` compiles, which led me to this solution.

Comment: constraint(?) - yes it's called [equality constraint](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/equality-constraints.html)